# Prove that there exists a $k$ such that $2^k-1$ is divisible by 11

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

How do I do this question using the pigeonhole principle? Of course, I could just list down values of $k$ such that $2^k-1$ is divisible by 11. For example $k = 10$ would nicely solve the question but it requires listing and when the divisor gets bigger (For example show that there exists a $k$ where $2^k-1$ is divisible by 21, it's harder and much more complicated to solve it.

Are there any hints how I can use pigeonhole principle to solve this question?

Comment: Not by using the pigeonhole principle, but still relevant: [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Comment: It require listing? What about the Fermat's Little Theorem? Since $gcd(2,11)=1$, then $2^{10}\equiv 1\mod 11$

Comment: @Scientifica Thanks! I'll look into it!!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan What if I don't list it? Then how would I know there exists a $k$ such that $2^k-1$ is divisible by 11?

Comment: @RCT Oh yes it is! I couldn't find it! But thank you! It's good that I have something to refer to!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the (potentially infinte) list of values $2^n$ modulo $11$, there must be distinct $m,n$ such that $2^m=2^n\mod 11$, by pigeon-hole. Without loss of generality, $m<n$, and then $2^{n-m}=1\mod 11$.